# Post comment button text cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When replying to a comment on the StackExchange app, the "*Post*" button text is cut off. I don't think this is a DPI issue as I should be using the default DPI for my device (213).

- **Device:** Nexus 7 (2012)
- **DPI:** 213
- **Keyboard:** SwiftKey & Stock AOSP

[image: Click for full-size version]

Comment: What is the "Hi", "I", "This"?? If it's an external app taking over the keyboard maybe SE app can't detect such a thing. Try to disable it while using SE app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's part of SwiftKey, it's the suggestion view. Built-in keyboard also has this and suffers from the same issue

Comment: Oh, OK then... let the team handle this. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed as of version 1.0.21 coming out soon, thanks!